# How can I load a true type font in luatex?

Tags: fontspec, luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load fonts that are in a ./fonts directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/load-fonts-that-are-in-a-fonts-directory)

I have a TTF file `zapf-chancery.ttf` in the same folder as my LaTeX document. How do I make this font available in my document?

Comment: do you really mean `luatex` and not `lualatex`?

Comment: I probably mean lualatex :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you did not wrote how do you want to use the font. Here is an example as a main font:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=/home/voss/]{zapf-chancery.ttf}
\begin{document}
\Huge
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks promising but do I have to specify the path? I can't expect others to run lualatex in the same folder as I do.

Comment: This answer and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/load-fonts-that-are-in-a-fonts-directory pointed me in the right direction. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If you use plain LuaTeX, you can use.

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\1={times.ttf}
\1 Times New Roman
\bye
```

And you should certainly use `fontspec` for LuaLaTeX.