# including font in .otf

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I'm writing my thesis at a company and have to write it in their default font.

How can I set a .otf font in Latex (using Texmaker on Windows)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,ngerman]{article}
\parindent0pt
\parskip6pt
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec [Path = fonts/,
    UprightFont = *-Light,
    ItalicFont = *-Thin
 ]
{AkkoPro}

\begin{document}

hello world

\end{document}
```

Latex throws an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

How can I install expl13? Is the way to include fonts correct? My fonts are in the "fonts" folder in the same directory like the .tex File and are called AkkoPro-Light.otf and AkkoPro-Thin.otf.
Is it possible to include fonts for Bold and others? (I've got AkkoPro in Bold, Light, Medium, Regular and Thin...)

I found a lot about xetex and luatex, but I don't know, what it is...

Sorry for my terrible english =)

---

I solved the font problem by using

```
\setmainfont[Path = fonts/,
BoldFont = AkkoPro-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = AkkoPro-Thin.otf,
BoldItalicFont = AkkoPro-Light.otf
]{AkkoPro-Regular.otf}
```

but now I´ve got a lot problems by the other packages and commants...

When I'm using the utf8 inputenc package, there will be an error in the header "!Missing \endscname inserted".

```
\pdfinfo
```

is now called "undefined control sequence"

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

in Line using \includegraphics XeLaTeX throws the error "!Dimension too large. ...

all these errors appears by using \setmainfont and disappears by deleting this command...

My header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,ngerman]{article}
\parindent0pt
\parskip6pt

%%%%%%%%
%Pakete%
%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path = fonts/,
BoldFont = AkkoPro-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = AkkoPro-Thin.otf,
BoldItalicFont = AkkoPro-Light.otf
 ]{AkkoPro-Regular.otf}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Paket für die neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings} % Packet zum Erstellen von Listinings

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{F3F3F3}

\colorlet{jsonPunct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{jsonDelim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{jsonNumber}{magenta!60!black}

\definecolor{lightgreen}{HTML}{3F7F5F} % comments
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{950055} % keywords
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{3F7DE0} % javadoc
\definecolor{turquoise}{HTML}{5FC0C0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{2A00FF}
\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
literate=
 *{0}{{{\color{purple}0}}}{1}
  {1}{{{\color{purple}1}}}{1}
  {2}{{{\color{purple}2}}}{1}
  {3}{{{\color{purple}3}}}{1}
  {4}{{{\color{purple}4}}}{1}
  {5}{{{\color{purple}5}}}{1}
  {6}{{{\color{purple}6}}}{1}
  {7}{{{\color{purple}7}}}{1}
  {8}{{{\color{purple}8}}}{1}
  {9}{{{\color{purple}9}}}{1}
  {:}{{{\color{purple}{:}}}}{1}
  {,}{{{\color{purple}{,}}}}{1}
  {\{}{{{\color{darkblue}{\{}}}}{1}
  {\}}{{{\color{darkblue}{\}}}}}{1}
  {[}{{{\color{darkblue}{[}}}}{1}
  {]}{{{\color{darkblue}{]}}}}{1},
}
\lstset{
language=Java,
keywordstyle=\color{purple}\bfseries,
commentstyle=\color{lightgreen},
morecomment=[s][\color{lightblue}]{/**}{*/}%,
}
%XML Style
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{turquoise},
  keywordstyle=\color{purple},
  morekeywords={android, name}% list your attributes here
}
% Allgmeiner Style für Listings
\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
tabsize=2,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=8pt,
showstringspaces=false,
showspaces=false,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
frame=none,
rulecolor=\color{black},
aboveskip=1em,
belowskip=1.5em,
captionpos=b,
breaklines=true
}
% die folgendenen 3 Pakete sichern, dass Wörter nicht so oft am rechten Rand herausragen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Paket zur Verwendung von Bildern. alternatif epsfig
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=magenta,
anchorcolor=black,% Ankertext
citecolor=green, % Verweise auf Literaturverzeichniseinträge im Text
urlcolor=cyan, % Farbe der URLs
backref % Back-Links zu den Kapiteln
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatflt} % Paket Bildpositionierung
\usepackage{marvosym} % Paket zur Verwendung von manchen Sonderzeichen
% Paket zur Verlinkung des Inhaltsverzeichnisses, als (vor-)letztes laden (es muss zweimal compiliert werden), nur glossaries muss danach geladen werden
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Paket für den Pagestyle fancy
\usepackage{dirtree} % Paket zum Erstellen einer Verzeichnisstruktur
\usepackage[
nonumberlist,   %keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym         %ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
]{glossaries}
% Entfernt den Punkt am Ende der Beschreibung beim Glossar
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
%sammelt die Einträge
\makeglossaries
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Allgemeine Informationen%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Titel}
\date{}
\author{}
\pdfinfo{
  /Title    (Titel)
  /Author   (me)
  /Creator  ()
  /Producer ()
  /Subject  ()
  /Keywords ()
}
```

Comment: What is your TeX installation (MikTeX, TeX Live, ...)?  You probably need to do some updating, but this will be easier to tell if you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then post the version numbers of the loaded packages, which will be listed at the end of your `.log` file.  For `\fontspec`, you need to process your document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, not `pdflatex` or `latex`.

Comment: As for the `path = fonts/` option, that only confuses the issue if the font files are in the same directory as your `.tex` file.

Comment: The fonts are in a folder named "font" in the same directory like the .tex file. Now I added `\listfiles` on the top of the document and processed the document with `xelatex`, which is configured `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in my texmaker. I don´t know, what the logfile means... Which part of the logfile is importand? 
edit: I've got MikTex on Windows and Texmaker as GUI

Comment: Parts of the logfile:
`This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2013.3.15)  15 MAR 2013 14:32
entering extended mode` and
`("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
Package: fontspec 2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
! LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
  
l.21 \input
            binhex.tex  % before expl syntax!^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)`

Comment: Are you hitting 'return' to let `XeTeX` try to finish.  The results of `\listfiles` comes at the end of the `.log` file, but you need to let `XeTeX` finish.  `fontspec` is old, anyway.  I recommend running an update; there's an option for it somewhere, but I don't use MikTeX.

Comment: Your version of the `fontspec` package (2.1, Feb. 2011) is quite obsolete; the current version is 2.3, released late last month.  Please try updating your entire MiKTeX distribution, including the LaTeX3 packages (such a `expl3`).

Comment: As for the `fonts/` folder, are you sure that's how you specify relative directories for `fontspec` on Windows?  (I have no idea, but I'd do it differently on Linux.)

Comment: I uninstalled MikTex and installed it again. Fontspec is up to date. Then Texmaker would install the epl13 usepackage, but it won't be found again. I don't know how to hit return, I'm only using the GUI. When I try to start `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in the console, there appears the message `...entering extended mode ! Emergency stop. <*> %.tex No pages of output. Transcript written on texput.log` I don't know, if the relative path is correct, I took the [example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/load-fonts-that-are-in-a-fonts-directory)

Comment: I can open the console in the Texmaker and type `XeLaTeX`. At the end theres the following File List: article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class - size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) - fontspec.sty 2013/02/25 v2.3 Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTex - LateXtest.tex" but the expl3.sty is still missing :(