# Custom font not loaded

Tags: xetex

I have an .otf font in same dir with .tex files. I'm using XeLaTex to work with this font, consider following code

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[xetex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{xunicode}
 \usepackage{xltxtra}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage{csvtools}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
  ...
  \begin{document}
   ...
     \begin{minipage}{84mm}
       \fontspec {Collator.otf}
       \sffamily 
       \centering
       \fontsize{32}{32} \textbf{\strut \insertName}
     \end{minipage}
   ...
   \end{document}
```

yields error

> Font EU1/Collator.otf(0)/m/n/12=[Collator.otf]/ICU: at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

On `\fontspec {Collator.otf}` line, but it should find this font in project directory.

Is there any other options or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: There are many things wrong with this document: you should not load `inputenc` or `fontenc` using XeLaTeX. You shouldn't pass the driver to `graphicx`; the `csvtools` package is obsolete and replaced by the `datatool` package.  The typical way to use a font with XeLaTeX is to simply install it with your other system fonts and XeLaTeX will find it automatically.  Is there a reason you need the font in the local directory?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I want to use this font on other machines, where I have no administrative rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many problems with your document.  See the following question for some basics about using XeLaTeX.

- [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736/2693)

It is possible to use local fonts with XeLaTeX but you have to specify the path explicitly.  See the following question for details.

- [Load fonts that are in a ./fonts directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12565/2693)

Instead of using `\fontspec` directly, you should always define a new font family to load a font.

Here's a fixed version of your document.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{csvtools} 
% This is obsolete and has been replaced by datatool
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newfontfamily\collfont[Path=./]{Collator.otf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{84mm}
      \collfont
      \sffamily 
      \centering
      \fontsize{32}{32} \textbf{\strut INSERT NAME}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{document}
```

[image: output of code]