# Install a font local to one particular document

Tags: fonts, installing

Is it possible to convert a ttf or otf font for use only in *one particular document*? That is, I do not want to have that font installed on my overall "TeX system". If my document folder is `foo`, I don't want that TeX messes with anything outside of `foo`. I'm using pdflatex.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/load-fonts-that-are-in-a-fonts-directory) is a solution (?) for XeTeX. I want to stick to LaTeX.

Comment: Converting TTF or OT fonts for pdflatex needs several steps and several files: you need TFM and VF files, ENC files and MAP files. Your aim is reachable in principle; but it requires expertise and time.

Comment: The problem is not the doing it for only one document. That's fine. I do this before installing fonts for testing purposes, or before uploading to CTAN. You just stick everything in the one directory and add the map file fragment in your preamble. But the conversion itself is just the same as it would be if you planned to do it for thousands or millions of documents. It takes time even if you know how. There are tools which can automate parts of it, but you don't get good results without fine-tuning things yourself. How much are you prepared to read and experiment?

Comment: I assume you already know how to convert a font and install it for use in latex (by using otftotfm or similar methods). Your question is how to limit the installation to one document. First do the conversion and installation in your usual fashion, for all latex. Be sure to update the FNDB and enable the Map file. Then, leave the Map file and font encoding in place (those do not contain any proprietary font information). Cut the font tfm, vf, and pfb files from the latex installation, and put them with your document. Move them back into latex when needed.