# How to use Freight Sans Pro in TexMaker?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, texmaker

I know that there are loads of questions like this, but I'm such a tex-rookie, I haven't been able to find an answer.

I need to use the font Freight Sans Pro in my Tex-document. I have the font downloaded, but I have no idea how to actually implement it in my document. I've gotten so far that I understand that I probably need to run it with XeTex og LualaTex. However, I don't know that my next step is.

- Where am I supposed to save the font on my computer?
- How do I decide between xetex and luatex?
- What packages/commands do I need to use I've placed the font right?

I hope you guys can help a new tex'er out here!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! First you could save all in the same folder... if it works you could go on. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.  See [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/124842)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565 and the linked questions will be useful to you.