# Can I get MS Word font on TeX?

Tags: fonts, msword

## Original question

I would like to make an identical copy of my Microsoft Word based CV in LaTeX. The Word document however makes use of Copperplate Gothic. I did not see Copperplate Gothic mentioned in the Computer Modern family, which I understand is the default family used in LaTeX.

How can I use Copperplate Gothic in my LaTeX based CV?

## Edit as per @Mico's answer

I followed the accepted answer to [this question][1] to make sure that the desired fonts exist as system fonts. When I run the following command:

`fc-list | grep "Copperplate"`

I get the following result:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/Fonts/COPRGTL.TTF: Copperplate Gothic Light:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/mnt/c/Windows/Fonts/COPRGTB.TTF: Copperplate Gothic Bold:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
```

I then tried to compile the document provided by @Mico using `latexmk -luatex test.tex`, but got an error:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'test.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "test.tex"'
------------
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
[\directlua]:1: module 'luaotfload-main' not found:
        no field package.preload['luaotfload-main']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
Error in luaotfload: reverting to OT1 L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric d
ata not found or bad.
<to be read again>
relax
l.112 ...lt\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault

?
```

## Final edit

I ran the following command inspired by one of the comments in [this question][2]:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex`

Compiling the .tex file after this install succeeded, and I was able to see `Copperplate Gothic` in my resulting pdf.

I find this quite strange because prior to installing `texlive-luatex`, I had done a `apt list | grep "texlive"` and could see that `texlive-luatex` was among the packages already installed.

But oh well... it works now...
[1]: [Can I permanently instruct xelatex in WSL to use fonts in C:\Windows\Fonts? If yes, how?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539831/can-i-permanently-instruct-xelatex-in-wsl-to-use-fonts-in-c-windows-fonts-if-y)
[2]: [! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378488/font-tu-lmr-m-n-10-lmroman10-regulartlig-at-10pt-not-loadable)

Comment: use lualatex and `\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\cgothic{Copperplate Gothic}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `Copperplate Gothic Light` and `Copperplate Gothic Bold` are available as system fonts on your computer, the following code sould get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Copperplate Gothic Light}[BoldFont = {Copperplate Gothic Bold}]

\begin{document}
Hello World, \textbf{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by the OP's revisions/amendments to the query: Since the OP has installed the two font files in the (slightly non-standard?) folder `/mnt/c/Windows/Fonts/`, the instruction

```
\setmainfont{Copperplate Gothic Light}[%
     BoldFont = {Copperplate Gothic Bold},
     Path     = {/mnt/c/Windows/Fonts/}]
```

should provide enough information for LuaLaTeX and its `luaotfload-tool` utility to find the font files, create the required hash files, etc.

Comment: For the OP: this would require you to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, instead of pdflatex.

Comment: I tried following this link to get MS Word fonts on my Ubuntu virtual machine https://itsfoss.com/install-microsoft-fonts-ubuntu/. However when I actually try to compile the above using LuaLaTex as described, it fails to recognize Copperplate Gothic as a valid font. Also `fc-list | grep "Copperplate"` yields no results...

Comment: @user32882 - I'm not sure I understand your follow-up. Are you saying that the Copperplate fonts aren't installed on your system?

Comment: @Mico it doesn't seem like they are... no, but I understand that it might fall outside the scope of this question. I logged another question in the Ubuntu StackExchange... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358270/cannot-access-windows-fonts-after-installing-them-on-ubuntu-wsl?noredirect=1#comment2326100_1358270

Comment: @user32882 - Assuming the fonts are indeed installed on your Ubuntu system, but apparently in a somewhat non-standard folder, you could add an option such as `Path={some/nonstandard/font/path/}`to the list of optional arguments of `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Right... Except I have no idea whether I actually have Copperplate Gothic installed on the Ubuntu subsystem, and if so, where I can find it.

Comment: @Mico I just made Copperplate a system font and edited my original question, would be awesome if you could take a look at the edit and provide some additional insight

Comment: Nevermind... I finally got it...