# Creating a booklet oriental style

Tags: fonts, page

I am trying to create a booklet in ancien Middle Eastern style, if possible in Memoir. I have some experience with Tex, but this is a pretty difficult thing to make.

The title page should look like this: [image]

In MS Word, I got this result, but I think it could look better in Tex.

Who can help me with a start?

- I need help with the font. In Word, it's the Special Ramadhan Font.
- And I need help with the page decoration.

I have no troubles with images etc, it's just the font and the page decoration.

Thank you very much in advance!

**Update**:

I tried this one:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Special Ramadhan Standaard}[BoldFont = {Special Ramadhan Standaard Bold}] \begin{document} 
Hello World, 
\textbf{Hello World} 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I got this message: ! Package fontspec Error: The font "specialramadhan" cannot be found. The font has been installed in Windows.

**Update #2**:

I opened the properties (eigenschappen in Dutch) and I followed the suggestion, but still no better result. [image]

I still got the message "! Package fontspec Error: The font "SpecialRamadhan-2O3z8" cannot be found."

Comment: For titlepages have a look here https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf. P.28 seems to come close, with code shown later. Also have a look here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation , which also introduces other Latex commands.

Comment: For the font: if you search here for windows font, you‘ll find you can use any IF you run Xetex or Luatex. Which Latex Distribution do yo use?

Comment: I am using Luatex (do you mean that?)

Comment: Fine. See e.g. the answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610544/can-i-get-ms-word-font-on-tex for an example how to specify your Windows font for a Latex document.

Comment: I noticed. Thank you!

Comment: I have to make one correction: I am using lualatex instead of luatex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the **windows fonts**, there's probably just a *typo* in "Standard". To check I tried a windows font on my system, which worked compiled as `LuaLatex` once I adjusted the bold-name (see properties in the fonts filename, probably in *c:\windows\fonts*).

[image: Arial]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
%\setmainfont{Special Ramadhan Standaard}[BoldFont = {Special Ramadhan Standaard Bold}% probably typo in "Standard"
 \setmainfont{Arial}[BoldFont = {arialbd}] 

\begin{document} 
Hello World, 

\textbf{Hello World} 
\end{document}
```

For further verification I downloaded a public font with a similar name, copied it to the same directory as the .tex file, and renamed it. This one does not provide a bold version.

[image: ramadhan font]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
%\setmainfont{Special Ramadhan Standaard}[BoldFont = {Special Ramadhan Standaard Bold}% probably typo in "Standard"

% download from https://www.1001fonts.com/special-ramadhan-font.html
% copied to dir of this file AND renamed font file

\setmainfont{srd.otf}%[BoldFont = {arialbd}] 

\begin{document} 
Hello World, 

\textbf{Hello World} % no bold font available in this one
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you copied the font file to the directory of the tex-document?

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working right now!

Comment: For the page border ornamentation, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650112/strange-results-with-page-ornaments might help.