# Strange results with page ornaments

Tags: tikz-pgf, layout, page, pgfornament

I am trying to use some ornaments for my pages.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\usepackage{titling}% for demo only

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, start chain, node distance=-2mm]
    \node (nworn) [shift={(5mm,-5mm)}, anchor=north west, on chain ] at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
      \node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (neorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,25}
      \node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (seorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
      \node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (sworn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,25}
      \node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, start chain, node distance=-2mm]
    \node (nworn) [shift={(10mm,-10mm)}, anchor=north west, on chain ] at (current page.north west){\pgfornament[width=10mm]{61}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
      {\node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{62}};
      \node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{61}};}
    \node (neorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{62}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}
      {\node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{62}};
      \node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{62}};}
    \node (seorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{62}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
      {\node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{61}};
      \node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{62}};}
    \node (sworn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{61}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}
      {\node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{61}};
      \node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{61}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is the logfile:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) 
 system commands enabled.
(./proberen.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfornament/pgfornament.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfornament/pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex
2020/04/06 1.1 pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarychains.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypositioning.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./proberen.aux) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: luatex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 1:1
* vratio: 1:1
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(89.62709pt, 418.25368pt, 89.6271pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(126.75832pt, 591.5302pt, 126.75833pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=418.25368pt
* \textheight=591.5302pt
* \oddsidemargin=17.3571pt
* \evensidemargin=17.3571pt
* \topmargin=17.48833pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian7.pgf)
[1]
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian62.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian61.pgf)
[2] (./proberen.aux))
 420 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 6 attribute_list, 3 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:64455,3:30670,4:5,5:22,6:1,7:1989,9:981
Output written on proberen.pdf (2 pages, 174982 bytes).

SyncTeX written on proberen.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on proberen.log.
```

Comment: compile again, until the message about changed labels disappears.

Comment: I am trying, but no change.

Comment: worked fine for me. Is your system up-to-date? And how do you compile?

Comment: TexLive2020 / LuaLatex

Comment: no problem here. After three compilations it is fine. Check your log-file for clues.

Comment: I have copied the log file into the edit. Could you please look at it?